# Reference a specific field of a document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access a specific field in a document in Firebase, and set a field of a different document in a different collection to the same value. Is it possible to retrieve just the individual field, in this case an int, or do I need to store the entire data set of the document into an object and then access the field from the object? The language I am using is Kotlin, in Android Studio. I really appreciate any assistance here.

I have seen some examples, but nothing quite the same as what I am attempting.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side Firestore SDKs (such as the one for Android) always retrieve the full document. There is no way within these SDKs to get just a single field.